# Spacelift - external state access - cannot create a workspace error

Tags: terraform, continuous-integration, cicd, spacelift

I am trying to use Spacelift's external state access however I get the following error:

```
Error: Error loading state error 
│
│ with module.service.data.terraform_remote_state.environment, 
│ on ../modules/service/ecs.tf line 79, in data "terraform_remote_state" "environment": 
│ 79: backend = "remote" 
│ 
│ error loading the remote state: Error creating workspace test-stack: cannot 
│ create a workspace
```

My block looks like:

```
 data "terraform_remote_state" "environment" {
  backend = "remote"

  config = {
    hostname     = "spacelift.io"
    organization = "<organizationname>"

    workspaces = {
      name = "test-stack"
    }
  }
}
```

I have external state access enabled on the stack but still get this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the caller stack is set to Administrative.